# Power Supply clicking noise

Tags: power-supply

After I have had my computer turned on for about 5 minutes, I start to hear a feint clicking sound which gets progressively louder over time, to the point where it becomes rather annoying. It seems like the fan is clipping something, but that doesn't really explain why the sound is feint at first? Would something be expanding inside as it gets hotter?

I have also confirmed it to be the fan, since if I put a pencil in there and physically stop it moving, the noise stops.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say anything really expands as the fan and heatsinc are there to stop the temperature rising.

It could really be anything but the usual culprit is it has come slightly off centre, or there is a lot of dust causing problems (such as one blade heavier than the rest).

I do not recommend that you open the PSU, but you can try using a vacume cleaner against the air holes to give it a quick clean.

Answer (score 1):

remove the PSU and open its case, make sure no wires or cable ties have contact with the fan blades. if it's dust you can remove it with canned air (i don't recommend the hoover).